# A gentler way to chase electrical sockets

Tags: electrical

I'm in the process of first-fixing a British 1930's house, and although the vast majority of the electrical chasing is done I'm still having trouble finding a safe method to cut out the brickwork for flush fit sockets. Chasing out runs for the cables is reasonably okay (Using an Angle Grinder and then removing the middle), but on a number of occasions I've had to replace whole bricks because they've either broken catastrophically or the mortar has simply failed.

This isn't such an issue when the wall is easily accessible from the other side, but I have a number to do in the kitchen and they're close together (I.e., increased risk!) and the other side of the wall is covered.

So, frankly, I'm concerned and surely there has to be a better way. The biggest issue is that no matter how I approach it, I always end up chipping away HUGE chunks of brick, sometimes up to whole quarters. And, combined with the old mortar - once that integrity is gone the whole thing just falls to pieces!

I'm pretty new to this, so please assume no knowledge on my part whatsoever - perhaps I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Up to know I've been chasing with a combination of the following:

Hammer and Chisel
SDS+ Drill with Chisel
Stich Drilling
SDS+ Drill with Scutch Comb

I'd appreciate any hints, tips or guides on how to do this in a safer and more gentle manner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been in this position many times. The problem, as you have discovered is the fragile nature of the mortar brickwork. The only way to stop it falling apart is to use tools that do not generate such a large percussive shock to the wall. One such device is a masonry saw such as a stihl. On the other hands if your brickwork is that fragile it is hardly something you should be leaving that way. Perhaps do the damage and re mortar it.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I would have just surface mounted the electrical. Everytime I've had to pocket brick it didn't have to be pretty. If you're set on doing recessed, then you get to patch the wall when you're done.

Comment: Surface sockets are really frowned upon over here and will diminish the value of the property. The old install was surface mounted (And badly done as it happens) and it even appeared in the home buyers report.

Comment: @Dan - I've done a fair amount of commercial work in Chicago and the only time I've even seen a recessed-into-brick receptacle was on a wall that had existing surface mount, which then had an extra course of real brick layed in front of it because they liked the look of fresh brick. You're a better mason than I if you think you can just do this and not have it look like a patch.

Comment: Hi Mazura - this is domestic. The walls are brick and plaster - so this is the standard approach over here in the UK

Answer (score 0):

I was recently at a wedding reception at a buidling that was remodeled in an older style. They used copper plumbing piping into old-style lamps (light bulbs). Not a normal thing but they apparently got approval from the local inspector to do something very interesting.

So, that said, you could consider running conduit to surface mounted boxes. Conduit comes in materials other than galvanized steel including materials more impervious to the outdoors like red brass, aluminum, and stainless steel. You could look for some attractive surface mounted boxes using one of these alternative conduits. Or consider painting conduit to match your design.

Otherwise, if you still want flush mount exterior receptacles, you are better off removing and repairing your interior wall than channeling the brick on the outside. Channeling leaves the channel to be filled with mortar, caulk, or some other material which doesn't look very good with the old brick exterior either. The best look would be accomplished from the inside.

Unfortunately, none of your options will be easy.
Good luck!